# Time taken to receive funding: A count variable?

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

I am trying to predict `time taken by a startup to receive funding` based on specific characteristics of entrepreneur. Regardless of a bunch of transformations and using linear or mixed effects model, the residuals do not nicely fit normality. I understand that there are generalized linear models for such purposes. But can time taken to receive funding (in days, hours or minutes) be conceptually treated as a "count" variable so that poison or negative binomial models can be fit?

Comment: Note that generalized linear models are appropriate for some types of continuous outcome variables; see the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) for examples. For your case, however, survival analysis seems like the best choice.

Comment: While we measure time by slicing it up and ignoring fractions, elapsed time isn't like a count variable in the same way as counting chickens is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Time to an event* (outcome variable) is usually analyzed using survival analysis methods - for example, Cox proportional hazards regression models if the interest is in relating this time to a bunch of predictor variables (in this case, characteristics of entrepreneurs). For your setting, the *event* consists of receiving funding.

The reason for this is that not all startups will receive funding during the period of study - those who will NOT receive funding will have their time to event censored (i.e., partially observed), whereas those that will receive funding will have their time to event uncensored (i.e., fully observed).

For startups with a censored time to event, their time to event will occur sometime beyond the end of the study, but we just won't known exactly when. For these startups, the censored time to event will be set to the time to the end of study (measured from when we first started monitoring whether firms receive funding).

Time to event data therefore consists of two pieces of information for each startup:

1. Their time to event;
2. Whether or not that time to event was censored or uncensored.

Comment: Thank you! In my dataset, I don't have right censoring. All the startups in this dataset have received funding. The time to receiving the funding is the only differentiating outcome variable of interest. So based on what you described, cox proportional hazard may not be relevant, right?

Comment: @BengaluruSun survival analysis works well, as suggested by this fine answer, even if no cases are censored. If all your startups have received funding, however, then you do have to consider how well your analysis will apply to startups as a whole as you don't have any information about the (presumably many) startups that never receive funding.

Comment: I tried Cox proportion hazard and the test for proportional hazard failed. I guess I am back to square one.

Comment: Cox proportional hazards models are not the only possible survival models. You're still on square 2.

Comment: Thanks @glen-b. Could you please point to other survival models that can be explored in R?